# virsh shutdown not working on linux guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, virsh, acpi

Solution to this issue is usually installing acpi on the guest vm and making sure the vm has the following:

```
<features>
<acpi/>
<apic/>
<pae/>
</features>
```

I have that, and still the virsh shutdown is not working.

When I have the VM console opened and run the virsh shutdown  on the host, the VM console turns to black without any messages.

However, when I run virsh list --all, the vm is still running.

This vm is a centos 7. The host is also a centos 7.

On another vm running ubuntu, when I run the virsh shutdown , I see a prompt on the console asking if I want to shutdown, reboot, etc.

How can I make this not interactive?
How can I make the centos 7 vm work?

Thanks.

Comment: In the guest, press F11 during shutdown and watch the messages.

Comment: I don't see any messages by pressing F11. The virt-manager gui shutdown also doesn't work.